# What was the original purpose for the binary system?

Tags: math-history, binary

Obviously computers weren't around when binary was first created... was there a particular use for binary back then or was it just developed as another number system?

Comment: That would refer to "Herrn von Leibnitz Rechnung mit null und eins"

Comment: To accommodate someone born with thumbs only!?

Comment: If Hagen's hint is too obscure, just google "binary notation".

Comment: From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Wilhelm_Leibniz#Computation): "Leibniz may have been the first computer scientist and information theorist. Early in life, he documented the binary numeral system (base 2), then revisited that system throughout his career. […] In 1671, Leibniz began to invent a machine that could execute all four arithmetical operations, gradually improving it over a number of years. […] In 1679, while mulling over his binary arithmetic, Leibniz imagined a machine in which binary numbers were represented by marbles […]."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is plenty of easily available information on the Internet on this topic.

Comment: @celtschk So even though it may first have been a kind of playing around, the purpose was very soon transformed to implement a binary computer ...

Answer (score 5):

From "Herrn von Leibnitz Rechnung mit null und eins" (Mister Leibnitz' computation with $0$ and $1$):

> *Diese Art zu rechnen wird nicht zu dem Ende angezeigt, daß man sie im gemeinen Gebrauch einführen solle, sondern nur allein, weil sie trefflich dienet zu neuen Erfindungen in Scientia numerorum* (This method of computation is not indicated to the end of introducing it to general use, but only because it is very suitable for new discoveries in number theory).

He also relates to those "three-bit" chinese oracles